# Jade error producing nested classes

Tags: node.js, pug

```
  .container-fluid('padding-bottom:15px;color:#fff')
    .row
        .col-md-6
            | column 1
        .col-md-6
            | column 2
```

what's wrong with my jade above?

Comment: Check your indents. There is an error.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in your example:

1. Wrong indents.
2. You can't set inline styles like that.

Try this

```
.container-fluid(style='padding-bottom:15px;color:#fff;')
  .row
    .col-md-6
        | column 1
    .col-md-6
        | column 2
```

It will compile to

```
<div style="padding-bottom:15px;color:#fff;" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">column 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">column 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise you would get something like this

```
<div padding-bottom:15px;color:#fff="padding-bottom:15px;color:#fff" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">column 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">column 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```